# Wordpress ultra slow if I click on posts?

Tags: plugins, posts, wp-query, pages, get-posts

I have 5000 posts on my website, which I have uploaded from a `CSV` file. This all went well and the website is fast on the back-end and frankly on any other page. There is one exception: if I click on a post, it takes 8 to 9 seconds to open a post, which is very disturbing.

I am using *year/month/year/post-name* as the `permalink structure` and have edited the **.htaccess** file with the code that is outputted by Wordpress on the `settings` page.

What should I do? I have used WP-Minify, but that did not have any effect at all.

FYI: it's a self hosted website, running on a fast server. The website is very fast, except at clicking on a post. Than it changes suddenly.

Comment: Are you talking about opening a post on the front or back end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that post hadn't tags and I had a function which outputted related posts based on tags. So what happened was that ALL posts were loaded instead of a couple of related posts. That was the cause of the slow speed...

Thanks for your help guys, appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately problems like these can be caused by any number of things (theme code, a plugin, or even data).

I've always had good luck narrowing down issues using the [Debug Bar](http://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar/) plugin.  (You can then disable this plugin once you're finished testing).

I've never used the [P3 Profiler](http://wordpress.org/plugins/p3-profiler/) plugin, but it seems to have good reviews and may also be helpful.

I think once you narrow down the real cause, you'll then be able to tackle the real issue (and post back here with more information if you need more specific help).  Best luck!

Comment: Thanks Jared, I used the Debug Bar plugin, which gave as result 1 deprecated query... Didn't solve anything though. It's still as slow as it was. You are right of course, I need to narrow down the cause, but the problem is that I don't know how to get to know the cause. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I agree with @Jared Cobb. Site can be slowed down due to many things:

- Theme's Code
- Plugin's Code
- JavaScripts' Load
- Site's Data

Considering all these, I choose...

- one of the fastest theme ([Frank](http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2013/01/16/frank-a-wordpress-theme-designed-for-speed/)) for my blog
- [WP Optimize](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-optimize/) to optimize my database to make it active
- [WP Super Cache](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/) to enable caching the website. It sped up the site much more than ever
- [WP Minify](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-minify/) to minify the JS to speed up the site

I got a good solution for my site using these. Hope they, in a combination, can help you too. Good Luck! :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. How can I check what's the problem than? How can I see in the theme code where I do something wrong? That would be good to know.

Comment: Anyways, what's the theme you are using?

Comment: Responsive (free theme)

Comment: Why not you check the WordPress's default themes like "T12" or "T11" and check the differences what they made for you. If so, then the problem is with your theme.

Comment: Shall do that. I actually managed to find the problem... It has problems with outputting 100 links to posts on a page. If I remove the posts, it is very fast... But that ain't the thing I wanted.

Comment: good studied. :)

Comment: Yes, but how do I fix this? I guess it is not logical to have a CMS that can't contain more than 1000 posts? That is very weird.

Comment: Can I see the page? Can have a link?